# How to use JuliaImages to create a smaller image given a starting image?

Tags: julia

I just got done exploring the docs for JuliaImages found [here](https://juliaimages.org/latest/quickstart/). What I want to do is as follows:

I have an image. It is a map of sorts. It takes up a lot of space so I want to index into the image and create a new smaller image that is just essencially a zoomed-in version of the original image. I know I could do this manually, but I want to create a re-usable script that I can use to apply this operation to N number of images. How can I do this using JuliaImages?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You can use indexing/slicing techniques to select a part you are interested it. That's essentially a zoom. You can simply wrap the slicing into a tiny function which takes the coordinates e.g., no rocket science ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "zoomed in" you mean focusing on a small portion of the image and making it look bigger, you can do this with ordinary array-indexing tools. For example, `img[251:500,147:328]` would extract a portion of the image.

If what you're really looking for is a thumbnail, my favorite approach is to use `restrict`. That is limited to 2-fold reductions. You can also `imfilter` (best with the `IIRGaussian` filters of [ImageFiltering.KernelFactors](https://juliaimages.org/latest/imagefiltering/)) and then call `imresize`. But there will be no beating the performance of `restrict`.